# How to avoid to duplicate the handle function for a reusable component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my react project, I got a reusable Score component to upvote or downvote an article.
I got a long 150 lines handleVote function for my article list on Homepage.
Now I want to add my Vote component the article details page and to the comments inside the article details.
The thing is that if I duplicate the handleVote function for  article details, 90% of the code will be the same, I just need to change the data and the setstates/api calls.

What pattern can I use to not duplicate the code that will be the same ? Should I split some of the handleVote function to an external js sheet ? What is the best practice in this case ?

Comment: So don't duplicate the handleVote function.  Identify the parts that are the same and reuse them.  This question could be made more concrete if you actually showed the code you are concerned about and showed your (unsatisfactory) refactoring of it to try to reuse 90% of the code.  Otherwise talking about code is like _dancing about architecture_.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the code as a helper function file and import in both component , if you want set state to be done add a callback function from the helper function which will help you add the set states